# SED or AWK?: Add character to each line after found pattern

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed, yaml

I'm using Jenkins multi-line string parameter to append new entries to a yaml file. But then I want to format those entries to match the yaml syntax.

The desired end result is:

```
var:
  - subvar1
  - subvar2
  - subvar3
  ...
```

What I have done so far is:

I'm running a shell script which takes that multi-line string parameter (an environment variable) which looks like `subvar1\nsubvar2\nsubvar3` and appends it into the yaml file. So, my line code looks like this:

```
printf "var:\n${HOSTNAMES}" >> ${WORKSPACE}/group_vars/all
```

The yaml file looks like this after that:

```
var:
subvar1
subvar2
subvar3
```

I am seeking assistance from you guys on how to add two spaces and a hyphen then a space before each line that comes after `var:`

**EDIT**: If SED or AWK is not a good idea to do this, what is a better way to do it?

Comment: Why not put the hostnames in an array, and then do `{ printf 'var:\n' ; printf '  - %s\n' "${HOSTNAMES[@]}"; } >> wherever`?

Comment: @don_crissti, I'm pretty bad at sed/awk hence why I'm seeking help.

Comment: @steeldriver, I'll try that!

Comment: @don_crissti Things become more interesting if `subvarN` contain special characters.  In fact YAML should never be edited with `sed` and `awk`, pretty much for the same reasons HTML and XML shouldn't.

Comment: @don_crissti Contrary to the popular belief YAML is pretty fussy.  It's really easy to break it with shell scripts.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, well in my case I'm sure that there will never be a special character. Either way, I've edited my question to ask if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: @steeldriver, your method resulted in only the first subvar written with the spaces and hyphen, and not the rest.

Comment: you need to iterate over `${HOSTNAMES[@]}` with a for loop.  `for h in ${HOSTNAMES[@]}; do echo " - ${h}" >> file; done`.

Comment: You could use a YAML parser for Perl or Python, or you could use something like [this utility](https://github.com/mikefarah/yaml) (written in Go).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are literal newlines in that variable, you can do:

```
HOSTNAMES='subvar1
subvar2
subvar3'
(IFS=$'\n'; printf -- "- %s\n" $HOSTNAMES)   # variable is unquoted
```

```
- subvar1
- subvar2
- subvar3
```

If you have the literal `\` and `n` characters, then this has the same result:

```
HOSTNAMES='subvar1\nsubvar2\nsubvar3'
printf "$HOSTNAMES\n" | sed 's/^/- /'
```

Answer (score 1):

With a bash array:

```
$ HostNames=( host1 "host two" host3 )
$ { printf 'var:\n' ; printf -- '  - %s\n' "${HostNames[@]}"; } > somefile
$ 
$ cat somefile
var:
  - host1
  - host two
  - host3
```